# How to convert Facebook REST API PID for a photo to its unique Graph ID?

Tags: facebook, rest, facebook-graph-api, photo

I know both the old Facebook REST API and the new Graph API fairly well. Through the graph api and given maximum permissions I can request a user's photos (its my app and my account):

```
client.Get("/me/photos");
```

This returns an array of json encoded graph api photos. The only problem is that it's not the total number of photos in the account. I checked this by painstakingly counting my facebook photos AND comparing it against a simple call from the old REST API:

```
select pid from photo where aid in (select aid from album where owner=me())
```

(the above from memory, but what I had worked well)

My count and the REST API confirm that the graph API is NOT returning all the photos in the account (I know about paging as well).

Does anyone know why this is? Also, does anyone know how to convert an old REST API pid (photo id) to a new GRAPH API unique ID. It's the only way I can think of to get all the photos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FQL is still available in the Graph API

`https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=select pid from photo where aid in (select aid from album where owner=me())`

Also, there's another property called object_id on the photo fql table which should correspond (if memory serves) to the id in the photo api table

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/photo/

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/

Comment: Sorry for the late reply DMCS, but thanks for your thoughtful response. By and large you were correct, the object_id can be used as the GRAPH API ID... most of the time. I'm finding that I can retrieve more photos in FQL than I can using the GRAPH, which is messed up. I collect all the object_ids from all of my photos and all of my photo_tags. I then use the GRAPH API's feature that lets you retrieve objects by just their ID. Of 716 photos, I get back 594 photos. 122 photos were not reachable through the GRAPH API. I think this is a FB bug. Probably permissions being applied differently.

Comment: Did you log the bug at http://developers.facebook.com/bugs?  At least now you know how to convert and get the photo id vs object id difference (kinda confusing for Facebook to develop it that way, but hey, what can we say, we're not Facebook are we).  Can you please give me credit for answering your question title?  "How to convert Facebook REST API PID for a photo to its unique Graph ID?" Thanks.

Comment: I would love to. How do I do that? Is it that "Was this post useful to you?" thing?

Comment: It's the greyed out checkmark beside my answer. Click it to turn it green.  Thanks :)  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?pid=11504724&l=3f088bdde4&id=99984862969
https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=select object_id from photo where pid="99984862969_11504724"
```

Response should be:

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "object_id": "10151373634447970"
      }
   ]
}
```